# C# - Multiple animated gifs in picturebox

Tags: c#, picturebox, gif, tile, animated

I have been searching around and have found many ways to tile images in a picturebox (drawing to an image, then displaying that image in the picturebox), and also ways to get animated gifs working on a form (simply setting a picturebox's image to the animated gif); I have not yet found a way to *tile* an *animated gif* in a picturebox, without creating individual pictureboxes for each tile.

**So in short, I wish to *tile* an *animated gif* in a *single* picturebox (or another control, I just don't want to create a control per tile) in C#.**

**Is this even possible? If so, how?**

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Place all the images of .gif file in an array. set a timer and at timer's tick change the image of picturebox to next index of array.